# Wordpress adding jQuery full Calendar support to wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fullcalendar

I would like to add a jQuery full calendar to my wordpress plugin. By default wordpress contains these widgets for jQuery : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress but my desired widget : http://fullcalendar.io/ is not part of the default jQuery installation.

Can somebody please detail how as part of my plugin I can add support for the jQuery full calendar? This question is related to another question I asked here : ["undefined is not a function" when I add a WordPress plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180306/undefined-is-not-a-function-when-i-add-a-wordpress-plugin)

The background to the problem is that under the twentyfourteen theme my code in the plugin works fine. Under a different theme - OptimizePress - the code does not work and I think it is because the jQuery is being loaded by OptimizePress and therefore is not including my jQuery support for the calendar.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your child theme's functions.php file.

```
function fullcalendar_jquery_enqueue() {
    wp_register_script('fullcalendar', "http//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.3/fullcalendar.min.js", false, null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('fullcalendar');
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "fullcalendar_jquery_enqueue", 11);

function load_styles() {
    wp_register_style('fullcalendarcss', 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.3/fullcalendar.min.css');
    wp_register_style('fullcalendarprintcss', 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.3/fullcalendar.print.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fullcalendarcss');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fullcalendarprintcss');
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_styles');
```

Comment: I have done that - but it still has the same error as I have shown in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180306/undefined-is-not-a-function-when-i-add-a-wordpress-plugin

Comment: I see, some type of conflict with the OptimizePress theme.  Can you enable the theme you are going to use and link me to your site?  I may be able to figure it out on there.  I've been dealing with the similar issues lately.

Comment: yeah of course I can - but I would rather link privately to you - not sure how to start a 'conversation' on stackoverflow other than to keep on commenting on this thread till it offers one?!

Comment: Shoot me an email, it's on my profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/574823/hawkeye126

Comment: Think i got it! Hitting the next problem now though. I'll try figure it out and email if i need to!

Comment: Do you have experience with OptimizePress?

Comment: Not currently, though if it runs on WordPress it shouldn't be anything out of my scope.